# Перевод из любой системы счисления в любую

Tags: python, python-3.x, алгоритм, python-2.x

Очень нужен рабочий код на Python, который переводит любое число из любой системы счисления в другую заданную (любую) систему счисления. (от 0 по 32 может быть и исходная с/с, и полученная) 
Формат ввода:

Число (Например: AA16342F)

Изначальная система счисления (16)

Система счисления, в которую переводим (8)

Вывод полученного числа (25205432057)

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Можно вот так:

```
def convert_base(num, to_base=10, from_base=10):
    # first convert to decimal number
    if isinstance(num, str):
        n = int(num, from_base)
    else:
        n = int(num)
    # now convert decimal to 'to_base' base
    alphabet = "0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"
    if n < to_base:
        return alphabet[n]
    else:
        return convert_base(n // to_base, to_base) + alphabet[n % to_base]
```

Тесты:

```
In [41]: convert_base('AA16342F', from_base=16, to_base=8)
Out[41]: '25205432057'

In [42]: convert_base('111', from_base=2)
Out[42]: '7'

In [43]: convert_base(33, to_base=16)
Out[43]: '21'

In [44]: convert_base(33333, to_base=20)
Out[44]: '436D'

In [45]: convert_base(3333333, to_base=20)
Out[45]: '10GD6D'
```

---

**UPD:** нерекурсивная реализация функции:

```
def convert_base(num, to_base=10, from_base=10):
    # first convert to decimal number
    n = int(num, from_base) if isinstance(num, str) else num
    # now convert decimal to 'to_base' base
    alphabet = "0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"
    res = ""
    while n > 0:
        n,m = divmod(n, to_base)
        res += alphabet[m]
    return res[::-1]
```

Comment: Спасибо. Это то, что нужно.