# Перевод из 10сс в 16сс Python

Tags: python, системы-счисления

Только начала изучать программирование, и на некоторые вопросы в интернете все еще ответов не имеется. Нужен код, который будет переводить число (введеное пользователем) из 10 системы счисления в 16. Написала что-то такое, но оно как-то не работает) почему - не знаю) может, кто-то сможет помочь?

```
def convert_base(num = int(input()), to_base=16, from_base=10):
    if isinstance(num, str):
        n= int(num, to_base)
    else:
        n= int(num)
    alphabet = "0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"
    if n<to_base:
        return alphabet[n]
    else:
        return convert_base(n // to_base, to_base) + alphabet[n % to_base]
print(n)
```

Comment: Как-то не работает это как?

Comment: Вам известно, что в шестнадцатиричной системе буквы только до F?

Comment: А, да, точно) Она просто не выводит получившееся (по идее) число. Введя условно 12000 которые в 16ричной 2ЕЕ0 на выходе у меня программа ничего не пишет. Я вроде понимаю, почему это, но как исправить - не знаю :/

Comment: Про то, что буквы до F - да, знаю. Просто код с этого же сайта, не заметила, пока вставляла

Comment: @рокки, возьмите код из [этого ответа](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/607809/211923), __не изменяя его__ и вызвайте функцию так:  `convert_base(input(), to_base=16)` ;)