# Как мне исправить код ,чтобы v увеличивалась только после того как каждый элемент из списка пройдет цикл(for f...) а не после каждой проверки элемента

Tags: python

> я хочу найти кол-во систем счисления от 2 до 10, при которых число 1988 не будет иметь одинаковых цифр стоящих рядом, в этом коде v это как раз кол-во систем счисления которые подходят под условие

```
n = 0
v = 0
for i in range(2,11):
    a = 1988
    c = 0
    d = []
    while a > 0:
        c += a%i 
        a = a // 2 
        d.append(int(c))
        n+=1
    for f in range(len(d)):
        if d[f-1]==d[f]:
            break
v+=1
print(v)
```

Comment: Уберите лишнюю табуляцию в строке `v+=1`, в питоне табуляции - элемент синтаксиса. У вас эта строка внутрь цикла из-за табуляции попадает.

Comment: и валидность кода проверьте: `if d[f-1]=d[f]` (должно быть `==`), откуда взялась `v`?

Comment: @Jack_oS вот полный код:
    n = 0
    v = 0
    for i in range(2,11):
        a = 1988
        c = 0
        d = []
        while a > 0:
            c += a%i 
            a = a // 2 
            d.append(int(c))
            n+=1
        for f in range(len(d)):
            if d[f-1]==d[f]:
                break
    
    print(v)

Comment: Самое первое и главное, это убедитесь, что код в вопросе отформатирован правильно, т.е. так как у вас в файле. Отступы в питоне очень важны и если вы вставили код с другими отступами чем есть у вас, то и ответ будет не о вашем коде, а каком-то другом. По этой же причине, не нужно вставлять код в комментарий (там форматирование вообще не работает). Изменяйте текст вопроса кнопкой "Править".

Comment: думаю самое правильное будет - написать код с нуля, а в вопросе хорошо бы написать еще что этот код должен был делать, а то в коде куча ошибок

Comment: @Zhihar, а какие ошибки?

Comment: Если я правильно прочитал ваш код ,  его можно оптимизировать, заменив на: print(0) т.к. “v” нигде не изменяется. Если бы вы описали что именно вы пытаетесь сделать, то возможно вам бы предложили более элегантное решение ;)

Comment: Там было `v+=1` и вообще я смотрю код только ещё больше со временем поехал :/

Comment: @MaxU    я хочу найти кол-во систем счисления от 2 до 10, при которых число 1988 не будет иметь одинаковых цифр стоящих рядом, в этом коде v это как раз кол-во систем счисления которые подходят под условие

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
def check(num, base=10):
    num, prev_digit = divmod(num, base)
    while num > 0:
        num, mod = divmod(num, base)
        if mod == prev_digit:
            return False
        prev_digit = mod
    return True

res = sum(check(1988, i) for i in range(2, 10))
```

результат:

```
In [109]: res
Out[109]: 3
```

PS [здесь](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/607809/211923) можно найти реализации функций для перевода чисел из одной системы счисления в другую.