# Перевод систем счисления

Tags: python

Доброе время суток, как через питон переводить числа из одной системы счисления в другую?
Лично мне надо из десятичной в троичную, но неплохо бы было узнать про все способы)

Comment: https://gist.github.com/bitsandbooks/2649444

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Перевод из любой системы счисления в любую](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/607802/%d0%9f%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%b4-%d0%b8%d0%b7-%d0%bb%d1%8e%d0%b1%d0%be%d0%b9-%d1%81%d0%b8%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b5%d0%bc%d1%8b-%d1%81%d1%87%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%8f-%d0%b2-%d0%bb%d1%8e%d0%b1%d1%83%d1%8e)

Answer (score 2):

Вот способ для того, чтобы переводить из десятичной в любую систему счисления:

```
n = 343**6-7**10+47
string = ''
while n > 0:
    string+=str(n%3)
    n//= 3 
print(string[::-1])
```

Ещё есть функции `bin()`, `oct()`, `int()`, `hex()`.

Answer (score 1):

хочу дополнить ответ выше и сказать, что если вам наоборот нужно перевести в десятичную систему исчисления, то можно сделать так (это фрагмент кода):

```
n = 100100111
print(int(n, 2))
```

здесь `2` - это основание системы исчисления, из которой надо перевести в десятичную.

Comment: В текущем виде ваш ответ непонятен. Пожалуйста, нажмите [edit] под сообщением, чтобы добавить больше подробностей, которые помогут другим понять, как он отвечает на заданный вопрос. Вы можете найти больше информации о том, как писать хорошие ответы в [Справке](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Код не работает.